# json_decode renders The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()

Tags: php, json, laravel

I use Laravel and the function `json_decode`. Amongst others, I use it within a popular module and it doesn't work there on in my own, very simple testcase. It seem to have something todo with my setup/settings. (I'm running it on pagodabox and locally). The data I feed it is from Twitter/Instagram, so the content is JSON.

Here is an example of where it doesn't work:

```
<?php

class InstagramController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */

    public function read($q)
    {
        $client_id = '#############';

        $uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$q.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id;
        $response = $this->sendRequest($uri);

        return json_decode($response);
    }

    public function sendRequest($uri){
        $curl = curl_init($uri);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: can you try dumping your response from sendRequest? What is the result?

Comment: Why are you returning a JSON object from a controller? Controller should return a string (or implementation the render to string).